# How did whatsapp handling special characters, unicode and emoji's

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am using openfire for messaging application every thing is working fine. I need to know how whatsapp handling special characters, uni-codes and emoji's combined client and server side.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special handling for this, you just need to send escaped xml to server.

For example, you can look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references
This is not specific to XMPP Servers.

Comment: please post the actual stanza here, or paste body which you are sending to server?

Comment: some of the characters when placed in the string, will generate this error.. You need to make them unicode properly.. Check following:
https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/37548

Comment: i have sent √π÷×‌​¶∆ in chat on both Ejabberd and Openfire server using a desktop client and it's working fine. Same message is received on B Party. So it's all about escaping special characters. There is no issue in Openfire Server, If we will provide valid xml, it won't complain.

Comment: Did you open the link i pasted in my previous comment?